# Как переконвертировать группу файлов из UTF-8 в Windows-1251?

Tags: windows, cp1251, кодировка, utf-8

ОС - WINDOWS.

UPD1. У меня есть проект на си, кодировка всех файлов UTF-8. Начальство попросило сделать в win-1251.

UPD2. Прежде чем написать сюда, я погуглил и тоже нашел кучу решений на php и для баз данных, к сожалению, разбираться с ним желания совсем нет.

UPD3. Насчет поставить linux и переконвертировать это вы круто придумали, ладно, у меня задача небольшая, а если кому-нибудь базу данных надо переконвертировать, тоже linux посоветуете?)) :-D

Comment: Раз Windows, то напишите это на Java.. это выйдет строк в 150 :) UPD: поправка: у меня вышло в 106 не самым кратким стилем ;)

Comment: а зачем это надо?

Comment: Самый лучший вариант - взять linux и iconv и использовать метод, описанный ниже. На худой конец, если нет linux, то можно notepad++, там в меню, насколько помню, есть "Кодировки"->"Преобразовать из UTF в CP"

Comment: А начальство как аргументирует свою просьбу?
Весь мир переходит на Unicode, а вы в другую сторону =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for f in ~/files/*; do
  cat $f | iconv -f UTF-8 -t CP1251 -c -o $f.out ;
done
```

Comment: хороший ответ, облом ток в том что WINDOWS :-D
но это не проблема, дома сделаю :-)

Comment: Такая конструкция вполне пойдёт под cygwin. "http::/www.cygwin.com - и ваши windows это смогут"

Comment: Поставьте SFU - считай тот же cygwin, только нативный, практически от M$ :-)

Comment: Ну iconv - это чисто gnu утилита. Что, разумеется, не означает отсутствия native win32 порта.

Answer (score 2):

Опять в php, использование iconv дает сбои.

```
function cp1251_to_utf8 ($txt)  {
    $in_arr = array (
&nbsp;       chr(208), chr(192), chr(193), chr(194),
     &nbsp;  chr(195), chr(196), chr(197), chr(168),
     &nbsp;  chr(198), chr(199), chr(200), chr(201),
     &nbsp;  chr(202), chr(203), chr(204), chr(205),
     &nbsp;  chr(206), chr(207), chr(209), chr(210),
     &nbsp;  chr(211), chr(212), chr(213), chr(214),
     &nbsp;  chr(215), chr(216), chr(217), chr(218),
     &nbsp;  chr(219), chr(220), chr(221), chr(222),
     &nbsp;  chr(223), chr(224), chr(225), chr(226),
     &nbsp;  chr(227), chr(228), chr(229), chr(184),
     &nbsp;  chr(230), chr(231), chr(232), chr(233),
     &nbsp;  chr(234), chr(235), chr(236), chr(237),
     &nbsp;  chr(238), chr(239), chr(240), chr(241),
     &nbsp;  chr(242), chr(243), chr(244), chr(245),
     &nbsp;  chr(246), chr(247), chr(248), chr(249),
     &nbsp;  chr(250), chr(251), chr(252), chr(253),
     &nbsp;  chr(254), chr(255)
    );

    $out_arr = array (
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(160), chr(208).chr(144), chr(208).chr(145),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(146), chr(208).chr(147), chr(208).chr(148),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(149), chr(208).chr(129), chr(208).chr(150),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(151), chr(208).chr(152), chr(208).chr(153),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(154), chr(208).chr(155), chr(208).chr(156),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(157), chr(208).chr(158), chr(208).chr(159),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(161), chr(208).chr(162), chr(208).chr(163),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(164), chr(208).chr(165), chr(208).chr(166),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(167), chr(208).chr(168), chr(208).chr(169),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(170), chr(208).chr(171), chr(208).chr(172),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(173), chr(208).chr(174), chr(208).chr(175),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(176), chr(208).chr(177), chr(208).chr(178),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(179), chr(208).chr(180), chr(208).chr(181),
     &nbsp;  chr(209).chr(145), chr(208).chr(182), chr(208).chr(183),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(184), chr(208).chr(185), chr(208).chr(186),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(187), chr(208).chr(188), chr(208).chr(189),
     &nbsp;  chr(208).chr(190), chr(208).chr(191), chr(209).chr(128),
     &nbsp;  chr(209).chr(129), chr(209).chr(130), chr(209).chr(131),
     &nbsp;  chr(209).chr(132), chr(209).chr(133), chr(209).chr(134),
     &nbsp;  chr(209).chr(135), chr(209).chr(136), chr(209).chr(137),
     &nbsp;  chr(209).chr(138), chr(209).chr(139), chr(209).chr(140),
     &nbsp;  chr(209).chr(141), chr(209).chr(142), chr(209).chr(143)
    );

    $txt = str_replace($in_arr,$out_arr,$txt);
&nbsp;   return $txt;
}
```

[Источник](http://mihalytch.org.ua/programming/php/convert-cp1251-utf8.html)

Comment: Мощно, если не найду другова способа, напишу тоже самое на си)

Comment: Да вы должно быть спятили делать преобразование таким способом :)) Просто используйте баш+иконв. Это ведь единоразовая операция, в конце концов. Думаю, быстрее будет скопировать на нормальную юниксовую тачку, а потом обратно, чем колупаться с пхп.

Comment: Или поставить линукс/виртуальную машину)

Comment: нормальный метод)))

Comment: И та же самая libiconv :)

Comment: И ещё. man iconv на тему опции -c:
-c When  this  option  is  given,  characters  that  cannot  be converted are silently discarded, instead of leading to a conversion error.

Comment: еще раз повторяю при больших файлах iconv может выдавать пустые строки и выдавать другие баги

Answer (score 2):

Если файлов не десятки, а пара, то можно воспользоваться стандартным Блокнотом из поставки Windows. При сохранении файла выбрать пункт "Сохранить как..." и выбрать кодировку ANSI. При этом, естественно, в региональных настройках везде должна стоять русская локаль.
Или пользоваться более продвинутыми редакторами. Правда, конвертации пакетной там нет.
А вообще специализированных shareware-программ под Windows для конвертации пруд пруди.

Answer (score 1):

В случае установленного php-парсера:

```
$curdir = opendir("...");
while (gettype($file=readdir($curdir)) != 'boolean')
{
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && ereg(".txt",$file))
    {
        $fh = fopen($file, "a+");
        $tmp = file_get_contents($file);
        fwrite($fh, iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $tmp));
        fclose($fh);
    }
}
closedir($curdir);
```

Конвертирует все файлы *.txt из данной директории.
Конечно их надо закинуть сначала в папку, доступную пхп)

Comment: Это упадёт со страшным грохотом в случае, если файлы очень большие..

Comment: С чего это вдруг упадет? php-cli и вперед :) Может нехватить памяти, но и это тоже поправимо, нужно memory больше скрипту дать. А вообще, не факт, что iconv под виндами будет работать как функция :)

Comment: С того, что файл берётся целиком в память.. много шума и противной нагрузки на систему, своп всякий, etc.. даже если не упадёт от нехватки памяти..

Comment: непредставляю, как будет под виндой такое работать, как и не видел ни разу как iconv под виндой работает) гугл пишет, что работает)

Comment: Ну я вообще против использования file_get_contents :)
Нужно писать $f=fopen(filename,"r");while(){...} - в таком случае можно использовать функцию mb_convert_encoding(from,to,charset)

Answer (score 1):

```
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, ...);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,  ...);
```

Как вариант до кучи :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Можно на Perl. Скачиваем Active Perl, устанавливаем. Проверил на файле из 2 строк - все ОК.

#!perl -w
use strict;
use Encode;
open (FFILE, $ARGV[0]);
open (SFILE, ">$ARGV[1]");
my $line;
while ($line = <FFILE>){
   Encode::from_to($line, "utf-8", "windows-1251");
   print SFILE "$line";
}
close FFILE;
close SFILE;
```

сохраняем например как convert.pl. Запускаем из консоли так: perl convert.pl UTF.txt Win1251.txt