# Как конвертировать все файлы в директории из windows 1251 в UTF?

Tags: windows, bat, кодировка

С помощью bat или есть программа, которая сама конвертит всё в директории?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант командной строки. Взять [win-iconv](http://code.google.com/p/win-iconv/) и выполнить одиночно

```
win_iconv.exe -t UTF-8 -f  WINDOWS-1251 input > output
```

либо циклически

```
FOR /R %%I IN (*.txt) DO win_iconv.exe -t UTF-8 -f WINDOWS-1251 %%I > %%I
```

Comment: у человека windows, насколько я понял.

Comment: Это пример для Windows и есть.

Comment: установил iconv по Вашей ссылке, выполнил команду
>C:\Documents and Settings\user>iconv -t UTF-8 -f  WINDOWS-1251 C:\Documents and Settings\user\Рабочий стол\123.txt >C:\Documents and Settings\user\Рабочий стол\12345.txt

и получил 

>"iconv" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: тоже самое

Comment: Либо я что-то не понял, либо этот вариант не работает =) а мне очень хотелось бы узнать каким образом заставить его работать..

Comment: А в PATH прописать не забыли ?

Answer (score 1):

Как здесь написано [в связанной задаче](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/8064/227636), можно на Perl.

Скачиваем Active Perl, устанавливаем. Текст программки

```
#!perl -w
use strict;
use Encode;
open (FFILE, $ARGV[0]);
open (SFILE, ">$ARGV[1]");
my $line;
while ($line = <FFILE>){
   Encode::from_to($line, "windows-1251", "utf-8");
   print SFILE "$line";
}
close FFILE;
close SFILE;
```

сохраняем, например, как `convert.pl`

Для одного файла запускаем из консоли так: perl convert.pl Win1251.txt UTF.txt

Ну, или как stanislav [в соседнем решении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/45612/227636) пишет, вызываем из батника для каждого файла в папке:

```
FOR /R %%I IN (*.txt) DO perl convert.pl %%I %%I_UTF
```

Answer (score 0):

[Программа для win](http://zavu.ru/O4SNPTm/)